# is it possible in React useState(<></>) has initial state is empty div or component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

my code is like that

```
const [component, setComponent ] = useState( ? )
```

What will be the initial value for component

```
if(true)
  setComponent(<ComponentA />)
else
  setComponent(<ComponentB />)
```

Comment: `state` stores your data; `function`s store your view logic.  Don't mix the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't store components in state but rather data to determine what is displayed. For example:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(true)

return (
  value ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
)
```

Comment: I have nested if conditions if(data[0]),   if(data[9]), if(data.length>10) depending on data length I show my component as data list or individual item. so can not rely on boolean value.

Comment: This is not his point. The gist here is to never store `jsx` as part of state. Your condition must be binded to something else. You could just as easily have a function which returns a component. The boolean here is just an example